# Harddrive connected in remote linux server?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Is it possible to detect the new Hard-drive connected in which slot of motherboard on remote linux server and details about the hard-drive using **dmidecode** command?

If possible please share the syntax....

Comment: I don't think dmidecode does that - running dmidecode alone dosen't seem to have any sata related information on it. You did try running it, and looking at the manpage right?

Answer (score 2):

It not answer about dmidecode.

Simplest way map disk/device to physical SATA port, that I found,

```
lshw -c storage -c disk
```

Simplest way to get details about Hard Drive, including model and s/n is

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda
```

Also very useful to map filesystem to partition for mounted and unmounted

```
lsblk --fs
```